# Pine Script (TradingView) color above Highest High

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to write a code that will color all the bars that meet the following conditions:
 1. their closing price is above 20-period Moving Average
 AND
 2. they close above Highest High price from given period (say 20 days)

This is my current code:

```
hp1 = highest(high, 20) //HH from given period
myMA = sma(close, 20) //my moving average to plot
plot(myMA)

myCond = close > hp1 and close > myMA 
barcolor(myCond? yellow: na) //if condition is met
```

The code seems to be logical, but doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've studied your script and have identified the following issues...

1. Your color condition is always false
2. <strike>You are assigning the color incorrectly</strike>

### Your color condition is always false

This is because your highest high logic includes the current *close* in question. It is impossible for the *close* to be higher than the highest high, because **it is** the highest high.

The solution is to append an index value to the *highest* function's response, to look at the previous period's highest high.

```
hp1 = highest(high, 20)[1]
```

**or** you could leave the assignment as is and append the index when you use it

```
myCond = close > hp1[1] and close > myMA
```

I invite you to refer to the *[series operator](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#op_[])*.

### <strike>You are assigning the color incorrectly</strike>

<strike>You need to move the conditional color logic above the *plot* function. Additionally you need to pass it in as a parameter to the *plot* function. I've included the complete solution below.</strike>

**Edit:** Upon further review, you can alter the color, the way you originally did. You just taught me something. Cheers!

Hope this helps

Comment: now it all makes sense, thank you so much and glad that I was also able show you something interesting! Cheers!